# Unix: How do I list all directories containing a program name

Tags: bash, find, directory

How would I list all directories containing the program name "minecraft"?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Programs called `minecraft`, or any files called `minecraft`? Directories in your `PATH` or any directory on the system?

Comment: Do you want to find directories whose name contains `minecraft` or directories whose contents include a file whose name includes `minecraft`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `find` and `dirname` to locate all *files* with the name `minecraft` in the current directory (adjust the search location to suit).

```
find . -type f -name minecraft | xargs -L 1 dirname
```

For finding files with executable permissions, you can use the `-perm` option for find (adjust the value to suit your search criteria):

```
find . -type f -perm +0111 -name minecraft | xargs -L 1 dirname
```

This should print the directory path *relative to the search location*.

If you want to search your whole system, just pass `/` as the first argument to find.

Answer (score 1):

If this is Unix, you could type "which Minecraft". If it is Windows, you could type ""where Minecraft". Add --all to the which command to list all the programs not just the first. Both programs search the PATH or in the case of Windows, the path plus certain runtime registry locations.

To find programs in places beyond the path, do the find command above, but add --perm to specify the an executable. Add --type f to limit it to files.  In ancient days, there used to be an slocate command which searches an index.